# My coverflow effect for the slider is not working in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have added the coverflow effect to my slider but it is not working.

This is my **tab1.page.html**:

```
<ion-slides class="swiper-container swiper-container-3d" pager="false" [options]="slidesOpts" #slides>
    <ion-slide class="swiper-wrapper">
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide class="swiper-wrapper">
    </ion-slide>

   <ion-slide class="swiper-wrapper">
   </ion-slide>

   <ion-slide class="swiper-wrapper">
   </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

This is my **tab1.page.ts**:

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

@ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides;
  slidesOpts = {
    effect: 'coverflow',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    initialSlide: 1,
    slidesPerView : 2.6,
    slidesOffsetBefore: 11,
    slidesOffsetAfter: 11,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    centeredSlides: true,
    coverflowEffect: {
     rotate: 20,
     stretch: 20,
     depth: 200,
     shadow: true,
     slideShadows: true,
     shadowOffset: 20,
     modifier: 1,
    } 
  };
```

But it is not showing the coverflow effect. It is displaying simple effect slider.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by referring this [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#custom-animations) .

You Can try with this.

And also change the duration as mentioned below,

```
setTransition(duration) {
   duration = 2000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i've solved by referring the Ionic team Github

try this it may help you: https://codepen.io/liamdebeasi/pen/vYYEwZM

i've just eleminated these two lines

```
let slides = document.querySelector('ion-slides');
slides.options = slideOpts;
```